# Read 2 integers from user input in c

Tags: c, input, integer, scanf

So my program has to read 2 integers from user input and print them. I use scanf, and the program will exit on bad input. However, when the input is  "3+2" or "3-2", scanf ignores the "+" and "-" signs and reads 3 and 2 as two integer inputs. I want 3+2 and 3-2 as bad inputs, and the program will exit. How can I fix it?

```
int num1, num2;
if (scanf("%d%d", &num1, &num2) != 2) {
        //bad input, exit the program
    }
    else {
        //print the two integers
```

Comment: Well technically, it _is_ reading two integers...

Comment: When you give the two values seperate them. eg 3 2

Comment: "-" Signs are not ignored.　(also "+" too)

Comment: What do you want it to do ? When I run this and enter 3-2 it print 3 and then -2 which are two integers.

Comment: Your program is behaving exactly like *I* expect it to.  How do *you* expect it to behave?

Comment: i want 3+2 or 3-2 to be bad input and the program will exit. When I run my program, it reads 3+2 as 3 and 2 instead of exiting the program

Comment: @user2851034 `+` and `-` is **not** bad input for a decimal...  I'm confused...

Comment: +2 and -2 are valid integer. The c function is right.

Comment: If you want `3+2` and `3-2` to be invalid inputs for `"%d%d"`, you are going to have to work harder — quite a bit harder.  What reaction would you want to `-3 +2`, `3 2`, `-3 -2`, `+3 +2`?  Are signs verboten?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes I want 3+2 and 3-2 to be invalid. Signs are not verboten. If the user enter -3 +2, 3 2, -3 -2, +3 +2, I want them to be valid inputs.

Comment: So the requirement is a space between the two values?  There's a meme "Be generous in what you accept; be strict in what you produce" (give or take) which says you should try to tolerate sub-optimal inputs, but be careful to produce correctly formed output.  You might want to consider it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, when user enter input like "3+2", a space is required between the two values. I just want my program to get user inputs and check if they are  integers. Is there any other way I can achieve this other than using scanf?

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to validate the string yourself.  Consider the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX_STR_LEN (50)

int main(void)
{
    char str[MAX_STR_LEN] = {0};
    int num1, num2;

    printf("Enter two numbers: ");
    fgets(str, MAX_STR_LEN, stdin);

    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_STR_LEN; i++)
    {
        if(!isdigit(str[i]) && (!isspace(str[i])) && (str[i] != '\0'))
        {
            if((i != 0) && (str[i - 1] != ' ') && ((str[i] != '+') || (str[i] != '-')))
            {
                printf("'%c' is bogus! I'm self destructing!", str[i]);
                return -1;
            }
        }

        if((str[i] == '\n') || (str[i] == '\0'))
            break;
    }

    sscanf(str, "%d%d", &num1, &num2);
    printf("You entered %d and %d. Good job.  Pat yourself on the back.", num1, num2);

    return 0;
}
```

The logic is as follows:

1. Read user input as a generic string.
2. Search string for offending characters or character sequences.
3. If none, parse string accordingly.
4. Sit back and gloat.

Comment: Point 4 gets my upvote. Point 1 is critical - `scanf` is just a terrible function that should be dropped into a deep well with stones in its pockets. You might want to consider that the user could put a CRLF between the two values. I think that would be legal, but your code doesn't (yet) catch it.

Comment: Any time `scanf()` needs two or more numeric values, you can have an arbitrary number of newlines between the values (from 0 upwards).  That is another advantage of `fgets()` plus `sscanf()` compared with plain `scanf()`. Similarly with strings (`%s`).  IIRC, only two conversion specifiers `%[...]`, `%c` and `%n` don't skip leading white space; everything else does, and white space includes newlines.

Answer (score 4):

Since the requirement seems to be at least one space character between the two numbers in the input line, the code will need to be something like:

```
char s[2];
if (scanf("%d%1[ \t]%d", &num1, s, &num) != 3)
    ...format error...
```

This (`%1[ \t]`) looks for a blank or tab immediately after the first number.  There could be extra blanks before the second number.  You don't have to do anything with the value in `s` unless you want to.

(*Fixed in response to an accurate [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21323253/read-2-integers-from-user-input-in-c/21324078?noredirect=1#comment32146777_21324078) from [chux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410359/chux)*)

Comment: `%[ \t]` has difficulties, for it scans a _string_ of indeterminate length (made up of spaces and tabs) putting the result in `char c`.

Comment: That's true, but easily fixed by `%1[ \t]` which reads one character into a null terminated string...

Answer (score 0):

Scan using `"%n"` to detect a separating white-space.

```
int num1, num2;
int n1, n2;
if (scanf("%d%n %n%d", &num1, &n1, &n2, &num2) != 2) {
  ; // bad input, exit the program
}
if (n1 == n2) {
  ; // no space between 1st and 2nd number, exit the program
}
```

Another approach, similar to @Jonathan Leffler, only accepts at least 1 space

```
if (scanf("%d%*[ ]%d", &num1, &num2) != 2) {
  ; // bad input, exit the program
}
```

Agree with many other say: Using the `fgets()/sscanf()` is much better.